# Show cell number in Anaconda/Spyder

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Using Spyder 4.1.4 in Anaconda, how does one show the cell number in the editor tab? In the Console it helpfully tells you the cell number currently being executed, e.g. "runcell(1, 'C:/script.py')", but I can't see a way to match this "1" back to the editor tab.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's just a generic name. If you want to name your cells (either with a number or any other text), you need to add the name next to the `# %%` marker, like this

```
# %% 1
```

Comment: A functionality of returning cell number would be really nice if that could be included somehow. The problem with commenting your own cell numbers is they don't shift when you insert a new one.